# SwiftUI ForEach open vs closed range

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to understand ForEach loop and ranges. Here is the code:

This is valid:

```
ForEach(0..<5) {
   Text("Number: \($0)")
}
```

This throws exception *Generic parameter 'ID' could not be inferred*:

```
ForEach(0...4) {
   Text("Number: \($0)")
}
```

I can fix it by specifying id:

```
ForEach(0...4, id: \.self) {
   Text("Number: \($0)")
}
```

I was wondering why the first range `0..<5` is *Identifiable* and the `0..4` is not. They are the same type `Range<Int>`. I just don't understand.

Many thanks!

Comment: They are not *exactly* the same type: the first is Range<Int>, the second is ClosedRange<Int>.

Comment: Oh my bad, I did mistake when I tried to look at the types in the Playground. You're right the second is ClosedRange<Int>.

Comment: Does anyone have a technical reason why engineers may have excluded closed ranges from the ForEach initializers? Being unable to use closed ranges(without id:) in this context seems odd.

Answer (score 8):

Reason being there is no initializer for the `ClosedRange<Int>`.  Refer to this [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/foreach) for the supported ones.